# A random string of ascii_letters + digits, but only starts with a letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random

I'm using the following simple code to generate a random string of length 10

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
''.join(choice(ascii_letters + digits) for i in range(10))
```

The problem is that sometimes the first character of the string is a digit. I don't want that. I want the first character to be always a letter, and what comes after I don't care about.

I can solve this problem to joining two strings (one of length 1 and the other of length 9), and generating the first one based on the ascii_letters alone. However, I was wondering if there's a simpler approach.

Comment: Your approach sounds simple enough to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `random.choices()`:

```
result = random.choice(ascii_letters) + ''.join(random.choices(ascii_letters + digits, k=9))
```

to select `k` elements. No need for `range` or `for`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
import random

def random_string_generator(length_str=10, asc_value=string.ascii_uppercase, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    both_str = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(length_str-1))
    print(f'{random.choice(asc_value)}{both_str}')
    return f'{random.choice(asc_value)}{both_str}'

random_string_generator()
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for your solution. For index 0 it should always choose from alphabets

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
import random
''.join(random.choice(ascii_letters) if i == 0 else random.choice(ascii_letters + digits) for i in range(10))
```

Comment: I think you mean:
```x = ''.join(random.choice(ascii_letters) if i == 0 else random.choice(ascii_letters + digits) for i in (range(10)))```

Comment: Oh yes no need to use enumerate

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for randomness which is usable in [security](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) contexts, you may want to consider, at a minimum, using the secrets module for making choices. Depending on the use-case, the result of using an answer given for an inappropriate context could [vastly](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3629437/iot-devices-have-serious-security-deficiencies-due-to-bad-random-number-generation.html) [differ](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/bias-random-number-generators) from expected outcome.

The below can get the job done for non security-critical contexts.

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from secrets import choice

result = choice(ascii_letters) + ''.join(choice(ascii_letters + digits) for _ in range(9))
```